# JavaScript: No toggle by click on <a> link

Tags: javascript, toggle

This is my code:

```
var works = document.querySelector('#works');
var cross_one = document.querySelector('#cross_one');
var works_navigation = document.querySelector('#works_navigation');
works.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      if (cross_one.style.display == "") {
          cross_one.style.display = "none";
        works_navigation.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          cross_one.style.display = "";
          works_navigation.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  );
```

Included is a toggle function which works very well. But additionally, I need a command like this:
If a `<a>` link inside the construction gets clicked, it should not toggle.

My idea would be something like this:

```
var allLinks = document.links;
allLinks[i].onclick = function () {
cross_one.style.display = "none"; };
```

But I don't know who to indclude it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure i understood your question, but you might be looking for something like this :
In your HTML, add your link like

```
<a href="#!" onclick = "doNotToggle()"> My Link </a>
```

and in your JS

```
var toggle = true;

function doNotToggle() {
    toggle = false;
}

var works = document.querySelector('#works');
var cross_one = document.querySelector('#cross_one');
var works_navigation = document.querySelector('#works_navigation');
works.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      if (toggle) {
          if (cross_one.style.display == "") {
              cross_one.style.display = "none";
              works_navigation.style.display = "block";
          } else {
              cross_one.style.display = "";
              works_navigation.style.display = "none";
          }
      }
});
```

and clicking your link will stop your eventListener function from doing anything.

Comment: Thanks! Generally, this works. There is now no toggle, if I click the link. But: It should toggle again, if I click somewhere inside the construction at a position, where not the links is.

Comment: then you can add another fonction toggle() setting your variable toggle = true and juste call it when you need to
(not sure i understood correctly tho)